# Exceptions while using GoogleSignIn

Tags: ios, linker-errors, google-signin, undefined-symbol

I'v added G+ button and tried to run app but receive that [image]

And i can't find any solution in google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the missing symbols in the error message.

Now look them up in the documentation in Xcode. Example, `SCNNetworkReachbilityCreateWithName`.

Now look at the resulting documentation to determine which framework it belongs to. In this case it is the SystemConfiguration framework.

Now add the SystemConfiguration framework to your project and those link errors will go away.

And most likely the documentation for the Google Sign-in library you are using lists the frameworks you need to add to your project. It should mention the SystemConfiguration framework.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add support frame works

- AddressBook.framework
- SafariServices.framework
- SystemConfiguration.framework  (now the error is focused on system configuration frame work missing)

for additional [reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/#add_the_sdk_your_xcode_project)